# C# change to http

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
      if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath == "/Text12.aspx")
```

What I like to do is I like to make the http be

```
    http://www.mysitename/Text12.aspx
```

regardless of if the user types in

```
    www.mysitename/Text12.aspx or 
    https://www.mysitename/Text12.aspx or 
    http://www.mysitename/Text12.aspx
```

Comment: What is the actual problem though? What are you trying to do? This just looks like string manipulation.

Comment: Will redirecting them to the URL path will help?

Comment: so you want to enforce http, regardless if the user types in https?

Comment: my gut tells me that tweaking DNS might solve the need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a shot at answering. Given you want the user to always use http. In some of my apps I am enforcing https via the following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
    {
      Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
      + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

This should also work the other way around:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(true) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(true))
    {
       Response.Redirect("http://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
       + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    }
}
```

**//edit:**
Please note, that I have set Islocal to true, so this will fire only when called locally - or on your dev machine as a likely scenario. You still need to fit it to your needs, or erase the condition altogether.